# How do I improve specific gravity in a 4 year old battery

Tags: battery, solar

The specific gravity indicates almost nonexistent acid level.   Barely above water.   What is the best way to bring this battery back to life.  It is a 6 volt solar battery.

Comment: What is the open circuit voltage? What's the voltage under load?

Answer (score 1):

**In most cases, take it on a trip to the recycling center, or trade it in to be recycled when you buy the replacement.** Lead acid batteries are a consumable item in solar service, and more so if the solar service is poorly managed such that they are not brought to full charge, or are over-discharged on a regular basis. They are a finicky and fickle part of the system, but less costly than batteries that are more tolerant of imperfect operating conditions.

You can charge the heck out of it, but it's probably past saving that way. You may be thinking "I can just add acid" but that does not actually work since the problem is not lack of acid, but where that acid has gone, chemically. Add sufficient distilled water, only, but I very much doubt you'll bring it back from the grave.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a standard lead acid battery, it is difficult if not impossible to reanimate it after a long time without recharging. The lattice of the active material changes into a status that can no more be reversed. This is why lead acid batteries should be only stored if 100% charged, and regularly recharged to compensate for the self discharging.

Otherwise sometimes a sort of pumping = short high current pulses helps to bring an unloaded battery back to life. These pulses must only be applied if the battery is below ca. 40% charge status. It helps to bring the possible insulated active material "islands" back into contact to it's neighbours. The temperature must be  checked against overheating. The location must be well vented, since H2 and/or O2 gases can be produced, which are an explosive mixture. PPE is mandatory to protect the eyes, face, skin.

If destilled water must be filled into the cells, the material like funnel and bottles must be free of any dirt or ions. No metal must be used. Any plastic containers that were in contact with detergents can ruin a battery. Some chemists say the open battery needs a cleaner room resp. cleaner air then a hospital's surgery room.
The reason might be the very tiny volume/mass of material needed to be chemically dissolved in the acid and spread over the surface of the active material thus ruining it.